# How to add multiple places on Google Maps API from a Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

If you are using www.google.com/mymaps you can create a custom map and load multiple markers from a local .xls file or an online Google Spreadsheet file. Is it possible to do this using the Google Maps API v3 when developing a custom map in JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

Read the data from excel (check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16172572/easiest-way-to-read-data-from-excel-spreadsheet-with-javascript) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939135/reading-excel-file-from-javascript) to get ideas) and use it in this way:

`x` = latitude
`y` = longitude

`pinImage` is created like this:

```
var pinImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter_withshadow&chld=%E2%80%A2|" + pinColor,
        new google.maps.Size(34, 34),
        new google.maps.Point(0,0),
        new google.maps.Point(10, 34));
```

When you have this variables create the marker:

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(x,y),
    map: map,
    icon: pinImage,
    title: "yourTitle"
});
```

If you have several markers, just create a marker array (`var markers = [];`) and add the marker to it:

```
markers.push(marker);
```

Comment: What if there are too many markers to parse by hand and what if I want people to be able to add places by adding to the Google Spreadsheet? Thank you in advance!

Comment: just use a loop enclosing all this steps, at least you must have latitude and longitude arrays and iterate over them to make several markers, just read it from excel spreadsheet and pass it to your function